# make two or more objects and use them in rotation or random in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, random, rotation

i have config.js file contain :

```
exports.smtp = {
    host: "smtp.mailtrap.io",
    port: "2525",
    auth: true,
    user: "3295b90cbc8837",
    pass: "x"
};
```

in another file i nget the smtp element like this :

```
var smtp = {
    host: config.smtp.host,
    port: config.smtp.port,
    secure: false
};
```

i need to create multiple smtp object and randomly choose which one to use
. example :

```
exports.smtp = {
    host: "smtp.mailtrap.io",
    port: "2525",
    auth: true,
    user: "3295b90cbc8837",
    pass: "x"
};

exports.smtp = {
    host: "smtp.mailtrap.io",
    port: "2525",
    auth: true,
    user: "3295b90cbc8837",
    pass: "x"
};
```

between the two objects will be used in rotation
.what ways might I do to make it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotation I am not sure but you can randomise like this. 
You can create your smtp details like this

```
const data = {
'1' : {
    //here you have your smtp details
    id: 1
},
'2' : {
    //here you have your smtp details
    id: 2
},
'3' : {
    //here you have your smtp details
    id: 3
},
'4' : {
    //here you have your smtp details
    id: 4
}
}

function getSmtpDetails(){
  //I am using 4 as i have 4 object. you should use as many as u have
   var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)+1
   return data[id];
 }
```

//then this should give you different object

```
 console.log(getSmtpDetails())
```

Alternativly

```
const data = [ {
    //here you have your smtp details
    id: 1
 }, {
    //here you have your smtp details
    id: 2
 }, {
    //here you have your smtp details
    id: 3
 }, {
    //here you have your smtp details
    id: 4
 }
]
function getSmtpDetails(){
   return data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
}
console.log(getSmtpDetails())
```